# Why is an onclick function firing when I type in an adjacent text field?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';


export default class CreateDog extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)

    this.state = {

        name: '',
        activityLevel: '',
        description: ''
    }

    this.newDog = this.newDog.bind(this)
}

newDog(dog) {

var doggy = {
    name: this.state.name,
    activityLevel: this.state.activityLevel,
    description: this.state.descriptione
}



 axios.post('/api/createdog', doggy)
        .then(response => {
            return response.data[0]
        })

}

render(){
    return(
        <div>
        <div>
            <textarea type="text" placeholder="dog breed name" onChange={(e) => this.setState({name: e.target.value})}> </textarea>
            <textarea type="text" placeholder="dog breed activity level" onChange={(e) => this.setState({activityLevel: e.target.value})}> </textarea>
            <textarea type="text" placeholder="dog breed description" onChange={(e) => this.setState({description: e.target.value})}></textarea>

        </div>

        <div>
            <button onClick={this.newDog(this.state)}></button>
        </div>
    </div>
)

}

}
```

Thank you so much in advance. I'm a beginner, so I recognize that this code my make you cringe. As you can see I have those textareas, which I have programmed to setstate upon change. I also have the button below that is supposed to collect the info on state, and send it to my server, and eventually my database.

Whenever I type anything into the textareas, the console is showing that the axios request is getting fired, but axios is not a part of my onChange function. It appears that my onClick function newDog is getting fired whenever someone types in the textarea and I don't know why.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `onClick={() => this.newDog(this.state)}`

Answer (score 2):

You have to bind this it as callback :  `onClick = {() => this.newDog.bind(this)}`

Answer (score 0):

Using parentheses to pass arguments will cause the function to execute immediately:

```
onClick={ this.newDog(this.state) }
```

You could make use of an anonymous function in order to pass arguments:

```
onClick={ () => this.newDog(this.state) }
```

However, you don’t actually need to pass **this.state** as an argument so you can just use:

```
onClick={ this.newDog }
```

As you are binding **newDog** in your constructor, you can already access **this.state** inside **newDog**.